# How to use Graph Explorer SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

```
public class GraphService
{
    public async Task<dynamic> CreateGraphClient()
    {
        string clientId = "";
        string tenantID = "";
        string redirectUri = "http://localhost";
        //string clientSecret = "";
        string email = "myemail";
        SecureString password = new NetworkCredential("", "mypass").SecurePassword;

        string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" };

        IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId )
                    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                    .Build();

        UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
             .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
             .GetAsync();

        return me;
    }
}
```

> NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IUserAppRoleAssignmentsCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.User.AppRoleAssignments' is not supported.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use "Graph _Explorer_" from your code?

Comment: Based on your code, you want to create a graph client by using c#. You can refer to the MSDN doc [Create a Microsoft Graph client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS).

Comment: I have read and applied this document but I get this error JackJJun-MSFT

Comment: As your trying to use ROPC flow using Microsoft graph here is the [sample](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2).Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended.