# Microsoft Graph: How to look up a user by personal email address?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I actually have two questions which may possibly be related:

Question 1: Why does user personal email address appear in Azure portal as User Principal Name?

Question 2: How do I look up a user by their personal email address?

The email address I will be looking for is the one used as a sign in name so I expect that it should appear in a property like `signInNames` as is mentioned below.

Steps to reproduce:

Log into Azure portal,  Look at a random user and observe their User Principal Name.
Note it appears in the format of a personal email address (joe@somedomain.com).  Copy the users Object ID.

In code, create a new `GraphServiceClient` and retrive the user by object ID using the Object ID copied in the step above.

```
GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphServiceClient();
User user = await client.Users[userID].Request().GetAsync();
```

In the User object that is returned, note the value of UserPrincipalName is not what is shown in Azure portal as noted in the first step. It is instead an assigned identifier: cpim_96fe-48b5-88a2-9ac960a6bdab@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com.

Attempt to find a user using personal email address [See also](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/577):

```
GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphServiceClient();
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request().Filter("userPrincipalName eq 'joe@somedomain.com'").GetAsync(); // Count = 0
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request().Filter("mail eq 'joe@somedomain.com'").GetAsync(); // Count = 0
```

As recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327823/find-a-user-by-email-address), this does not work either:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users3 = await client.Users.Request().Filter("signInNames/any(x:x/value eq 'joe@somedomain.com')").GetAsync(); // error Filter not supported.
```

My Azure Application has User.ReadWrite.All permission.  Personal email address does not appear as any property value for any object I retrieve.

EDIT

In response to the answer posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/65589/how-to-look-up-a-user-by-personal-email-address.html) I tried this code:

```
// Exact call to graph:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id%20eq%20'my.name@outlook.com')
    
    Error message:
    
    System.NotSupportedException : The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IUserAppRoleAssignmentsCollectionPage' on 'Microsoft.Graph.User.AppRoleAssignments' is not supported.
    
    [Question regarding above error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776361/how-to-use-graph-explorer-sdk)
    
    [Instruction to use GraphClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS)
```

Using `GraphServiceClient`  here is how I implemented your answer.  In both cases the call to graph returns users however the properties for the users are not populated.  My application has permission User.ReadWrite.All, User.ManageIdentities.All, Domain.ReadWrite.All.  Is this a permissions problem?

```
    public async Task<User> GetUserByEmailAddress2(string email)
    {
        GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphServiceClient();
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request().Filter($"otherMails/any(id:id eq '{email}')").GetAsync();
        var nonnullusers = users.Where(x => x.OtherMails?.Any() ?? false).ToList(); // count = 0
        
        users = await client.Users.Request().Filter($"identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'LeaderAnalytics.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}')").GetAsync();
        nonnullusers = users.Where(x => x.Id == email).ToList(); // count = 0

        return users[0];
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide links to documentation that supports this scenario? Sometimes, if you we can find the documentation, or something close to it, we can make it work. Also, is this an Azure B2C scenario?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To search users when email address is populated as Alternate Email (otherMails attribute):**

- graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id eq 'user@example.com')

**To search users when email address is populated as Sign-in Name (signInNames attribute):**

- graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'user@example.com')

Comment: For others trying to augment the identities bit. you MUST include issuer and you CANT include signInType. also it's now available in v1.0

Answer (score 7):

When using the [C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/) your call would be:

```
var users = await _graphClient.Users.Request()
                .Filter($"identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq '{emailAddress}')")
                .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. Here is what worked. You have to have the correct permissions, though.

I'm using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 as the endpoint.

```
var officeUser = await graph.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter($"mail eq '{emailAddress}'")
            .Select(e => new {
            e.DisplayName,
            e.Mail,
            e.Id
            })
            .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Few days of searching for a answer that works I tried multiple things in Graph Explorer and found what works for my scenario is.

This will get users in a list and form comma separated string and use it as filter or if you just want for one user use `eq` operator.

```
var userBatchStr = "'user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com'";

// Get Multiple Users
var users = this.graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Filter($"userPrincipalName in ({userBatchStr})")
                .GetAsync()
                .Result;

// Get Single User
var user = this.graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Filter($"userPrincipalName eq 'user1@domain.com'")
                .GetAsync()
                .Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try these Graph Calls:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id eq 'user@example.com')
> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'user@example.com')

via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) after signing-in with Global Administrator or User Administrator account by clicking on Sign in to Graph Explorer button on the left pane. Also make sure the user account that you are using is a member account in your B2C tenant (created via Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Users > New User > Create User option) and is not a guest or signed-up user.

Please let me know if this works and if you are making these calls under same user's context from your code.

Comment: Please see the edit I made to my question which documents the error messageI receive when running this code.  Note also that data is not returned when the same queries are executed via `GraphServiceClient`.

Comment: Which authentication flow you have used to obtain the token from Azure AD?

Comment: Implicit flow.  Why does this matter please?  I am able to access the properties of the objects.

Comment: I wanted to understand if you are using user context or application context for this purpose. Before looking into the code I am more interested in finding out if you are able to get the results via graph explorer with same user context. Have you had a chance to try that? If it works with graph explorer, we can eliminate permissions issues. I have tested above graph calls and works perfectly for me. It is important to narrow down the issue before we look for the resolution.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question where I queried the graph directly without `GraphServiceClient`.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
Query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id eq 'my.name@outlook.com')

"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'otherMails' on type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Web.Models._1._0.Profile'.",

How does graph know which AD tenant to query?

Comment: It checks the domain name suffix in the upn of the signed-in user to identify the tenant. Which is why the user who is making these calls should be a member user in that tenant and not a guest user or signed up user.

Comment: OK thank you for that explanation. I am a member user in my tenant.  Please see the error msg in my prior comment.

Comment: If you run PowerShell cmdlet, get-azureaduser -objectid <object_id_of_user> | fl, do you see the value populated for otherMails attribute of the user?

Comment: Please see this in the question:  Question 2: How do I look up a user by their personal email address?

Comment: I've included both calls in my initial response:
for otherMails attribute: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id eq 'user@example.com') 
for signinName attribute: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'user@example.com')
If you have the value populated in signInName, you are supposed to use second call. If the value is in otherMails attribute, use the first call. You can't use the call for otherMails attribute to search for signInName.

Comment: Thank you @AmanpreetSingh_msft.  Please post your queries as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this API to get information

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid) | userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode